# Can gamlasso accept sparse model matrices class "dgCMatrix"?

Tags: sparse-matrix, gam

Can gamlasso from the plsmselect package accept sparse model matrices class "dgCMatrix"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the `plsmselect` package does not accept sparse model matrices. We'll try to implement this for future versions.